# How to call geom.Polygonize() with OGR?

Tags: python, gdal, ogr

The Python documentation for OGR lists a [Polygonize() method](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Geometry-class.html#Polygonize) belonging to the Geometry class, [as does the C documentation](http://www.gdal.org/classOGRGeometry.html).  The docstring suggests it can be called on a geometry object of type "MultiLinestring", however doing so results in an AttributeError.  Other methods such as Buffer() work fine.

Did they move or remove this in GDAL 2.x?  `Lib/site-packages/osgeo/ogr.py` does not contain a Polygonize() function.  It does say "OGR 1.9.0" in the documentation, but I would assume this normally means OGR >= 1.9.0.

Currently running gdal version 2.2.4.

Code sample:

```
multiline = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbMultiLineString)
multiline.AddGeometry(line)

polygon = multiline.Polygonize()
```

Results in:

```
AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Polygonize` method is not available in the python bindings in GDAL 2.2.4. Although it has been around in the core C++ library since GDAL 1.9.0), it was only exposed in the python bindings at GDAL 2.3 ([relevant commit](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/commit/742babd46c6d88842e66df7930cc11bcb85c6a5e)).

However, a workaround is to use the `ogr.BuildPolygonFromEdges` method:

```
from osgeo import ogr
ogr.UseExceptions()

wkt = """LINESTRING(148.479859015579 -30.082172000762046,150.545288703079 -29.58660013074214,150.896851203079 -31.479043224714392,148.699585578079 -31.815735504845552,148.479859015579 -30.082172000762046)"""

line = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(wkt)
multiline = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbMultiLineString)
multiline.AddGeometry(line)

polygon = ogr.BuildPolygonFromEdges(multiline)

print(polygon.ExportToWkt())
```

Outputs:

```
POLYGON ((148.479859015579 -30.082172000762,150.545288703079 -29.5866001307421,150.896851203079 -31.4790432247144,148.699585578079 -31.8157355048456,148.479859015579 -30.082172000762))
```

If you need the GEOS based `Polygonize` method, either use fiona and shapely or upgrade to gdal 2.3.

Comment: Thank you, this does indeed work.  Unfortunately I'm looking for equivalent behavior to shapely's polygonize(), which is able to correct for self-intersections.  The docs suggest that OGR's geom.Polygonize() uses GEOS, which is what shapely is based around, so I was hoping there'd be a 1:1 there

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  The answer I was looking for.  I searched for a commit but I was looking in the wrong place.  I ended up using shapely but I'll try updating GDAL instead, trying to avoid extra package requirements.